# Kafakacomsumer for R fetching

Tags: r, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, rkafka

I am working on kafka . I have created kafka producer on my server . I want to get data from kafkaproducer to my local system in r.

I have tried following code in R:

```
library(rkafka)
consumer1<-rkafka.createConsumer("ipaddress:9092","mytest")

consumer11 <-  rkafka.read(consumer1)
```

It throws following error:

```
[1] "Java-Object{com.musigma.consumer.MuConsumer@3349e9bb}"
Unable to connect to zookeeper server
org.I0Itec.zkclient.exception.ZkTimeoutException: Unable to connect to zookeeper server within 
timeout: 100000
at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient.connect(ZkClient.java:880)
at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient.<init>(ZkClient.java:98)
at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient.<init>(ZkClient.java:84)
at kafka.consumer.ZookeeperConsumerConnector.connectZk(ZookeeperConsumerConnector.scala:156)
at kafka.consumer.ZookeeperConsumerConnector.<init>(ZookeeperConsumerConnector.scala:114)
at kafka.javaapi.consumer.ZookeeperConsumerConnector.<init>(ZookeeperConsumerConnector.scala:65)
at kafka.javaapi.consumer.ZookeeperConsumerConnector.<init>(ZookeeperConsumerConnector.scala:67)
at kafka.consumer.Consumer$.createJavaConsumerConnector(ConsumerConnector.scala:100)
at kafka.consumer.Consumer.createJavaConsumerConnector(ConsumerConnector.scala)
at com.musigma.consumer.MuConsumer.CreateConsumer(MuConsumer.java:99)
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.musigma.consumer.MuConsumer.startConsumer(MuConsumer.java:133)
```

My zookeeper is running on the ipaddress successfully.

Answer (score 0):

The first parameter is Zookeeper, which runs on port 2181

You've given it Kafka port

Source - https://github.com/cran/rkafkajars/blob/master/java/com/musigma/consumer/MuConsumer.java#L87

Note: Looks like that library isn't maintained and using Zookeeper to connect with a consumer is practically deprecated, so maybe try finding another library

Comment: Hi i have tried with port number "2181" but got the same error. Thank you

Comment: If it still times out connecting, then it's a network issue or Zookeeper isn't actually running

Comment: @OneCricketeer, a problem that I'm facing is that *there is no other library* for R (I'm not the OP). This is a big problem for R, and RStudio's recommendation (on a support call) was to bring up an instance of Spark just so that we can use the `sparklyr` package. That's a *lot* of a heavy lift just to get a kafka consumer in R. I'm currently looking at the prospects of wrapping [librfkafka](https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka) in `cpp11` or `Rcpp`, but I recall the last time I considered doing it, the complexity was more than a trivial "wrapping". Alternatives? Python/`reticulate`. Ugh.

Comment: @r2evans I don't actually know R, but Python support is fairly good. Depending on your actual needs, you could also use Kafka Connect to write to some database that R supports

Comment: Yes, I'm familiar with the goodness of the python kafka client, which is why it's likely to be where I go when I am again tired/frustrated by trying to "wrap" librdkafka. My need for kafka is to influence the data *before* it's sent to the DB, but thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @r2evans In Kafka Connect framework, Single-Message-Transforms can do that, but would require JVM code.